# Is it a good practice to lock some data outside if-else and unlock inside if-else

Tags: go, mutex

When I test `rf.state == candidate`, there could be a race. So I lock the struct `rf` before that. I want to make sure `rf.state` appears exactly in the `if` condition test so I can use its most current value.

```golang
...
func (rf *Raft) runElection() {
    rf.mu.Lock()
    rf.currentTerm += 1
    rf.votedFor = rf.me
    rf.votes = 1
    rf.mu.Unlock()

    for server := range rf.peers {
        rf.mu.Lock()
        if server != rf.me && rf.state == candidate {
            rf.mu.Unlock()
            go rf.sendRequestVote(server)
        } else {
            rf.mu.Unlock()
        }
    }
}

...
```

Is there any other idiomatic way to lock the data in similar situations (if-else, switch...)?

---

EDITS:
Here is some other code of mine.

```golang
...
rf.mu.Lock()
switch rf.state {
case follower:
        rf.mu.Unlock()

        select {
        case <-rf.chanAppends:
        case <-rf.chanGrantVotes:
        case <-time.After(time.Duration(500+rand.Intn(1000)) * time.Millisecond):
                rf.mu.Lock()
                rf.state = candidate
                rf.mu.Unlock()
        }
case candidate:
        rf.mu.Unlock()
        ...
case leader:
        rf.mu.Unlock()
        ...
```

To use the current `rf.state` upon `switch`, I have to lock at the outside and unlock it at the inside. What bothers me is that for every case I have to unlock for every cases (making the code less clean and readable?). And there is some blocking (e.g. `time.After(...)`) going on to make a timer inside every case so I see no way of using `defer` to help me. I guess it's some tradeoff I have to make if I don't want to alter the logical structure of this `switch`?

Comment: If you want to avoid the if-else and double-unlock you could do the following: lock, then `canSend := (server != rf.me && rf.state == candidate)`, then unlock, and then `if canSend { go rf.send... }`. Although I don't think your approach is necessarily bad practice. IMO you can keep the if-else approach.

Comment: I'd go with what @mkopriva offered: it's easier to calculate a value while the state is locked and then use it freely. I'd argue it could even boost readability by explicitly "naming" the condition being tested.

Comment: @kostix another approach, maybe overkill, would be to write a method that locks, defers unlock, and returns the result of the conditional expression. Then one would end up with `if rf.canSendRequestVote(server) { go rf.sendRequestVote(server) }`.

Comment: isnt that still a race condition? from the time you unlock to calling sendRequestVote, the state could have already changed.

Comment: We don't know what `sendRequestVote` does, @TheFool, so it's impossible to judge just from the available information. Note that the `server` variable is not a part of the state so if the method itself does not access the contents `rf` points at, all is OK. Well, a good heads-up anyway for the OP to ponder. +1

Comment: My bad, didn't provide enough information. And yeah my intention is to test `rf.state` right at the time when I enter `if` so caching the condition in a variable won't do. I'll edit the description.

Answer (score 1):

While your code looks okay, you can always extract parts into their own functions to make use of `defer`.

```
func (rf *Raft) runElection() {
    // ...

    for server := range rf.peers {
        tryVote(rf, server)
    }
}

func tryVote(rf *Raft, server xxx) {
    rf.mu.Lock()
    defer rf.mu.Unlock()
    if server != rf.me && rf.state == candidate {
        go rf.sendRequestVote(server)
    }
}
```

This is especially helpful when your code gets more complex and you want to make ABSOLUTELY sure the mutex gets unlocked once you return from some code section.